# Gravity form data to excel file

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form Is there a way for the forms to be sent as an Excel or CSV file to my staff?  The information is currently be sent within an email and the staff then has to individually copy the fields into their systems. When the form get filled by anyone is it possible that it can sent in excel format.
Please suggest me any free addon or easy method i have not knowledge about code

Comment: Mayby it will help you https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-entries-in-excel/.

Answer (score 0):

If you need free addon for your purpose you have to try '[Gravity Forms Entries in Excel](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-entries-in-excel/)' & '[Gravity PDF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-pdf-extended/)'. Since I had only seen the documentation of these plugin I can't tell you about it's working but it seems good according to the users rating.

Well I suggest you to try both of them and keeps that plugin which you likes the most.

But if you want to use the best plugin at a very low cost you should try "[WordPress Gravity Forms PDF & Excel](https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-gravity-forms-pdf/23642805)". Since i am using this plugin i can say this plugin works very well and have the best support team. I am saying it because they resolved my problem in less than 48 hours.